# Visual Studio 11 Beta / IIS 7.5: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common V11 not found

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I work with Visual Studio 11 Beta (MVC3 + .Net 4.0). I deployed the project to the IIS 7.5 (MS 2008 Server), when I generate a report, I've got the following error:

**System.IO.FileNotFoundException**: Die Datei oder Assembly **"Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"** or one of its dependencies was not found. The system cannot find the file specified.

On my local developer machine I can't find the "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll" Version 11.0.0.0 only 10, but local it works fine! :(

Comment: What specifically do you need to know?

Comment: I had the same problem. I found it odd that the Common dll was not in the Visual Studio solution or added as a reference. Especially since this is easily solved by marking the references to 'Copy To Local'

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and I followed [these steps](http://am22tech.com/s/22/Forum1/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=12)!

Hope this helps.

To summarize the link, go to the GAC from the **command line** and find your problem DLLs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\Pick_A_Framework_Version\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\Pick_A_Framework_Version\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
```

and possibly:

```
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\Pick_A_Framework_Version\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\Pick_A_Framework_Version\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
```

Copy those dlls to your bin folder, and you should be all set.

Comment: link to "these steps" above is broken.  The answer that was most helpful to me is [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18635865/2788458](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18635865/2788458)

Answer (score 0):

curlackhacker's suggestion got me past the error, but then exceptions occured with internalRender. I suggest using my answer as a last resort because I can't explain exactly why it works, but this is the only thing that worked for me:

Install report builder on the server.

Note: this solved the same problem in .net 4.0 IIS 7 and the project was a webservice, so as I said, try curlackhackers solution first.. Good luck readers.