# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms'

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to use the report viewer in asp.net and have uploaded my site. However, when my page containing the report viewer is loaded, it shows the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is my first time deploying an ASP.NET website, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: See this post : [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.XmlSerializers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494641/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms-xmlserializers)

Answer (score 68):

This link gave me a clue that I didn't install a required update (my problemed concerned version nr, v11.0.0.0)

[ReportViewer 2012 Update 'Gotcha' to be aware of](https://deep.data.blog/2012/12/11/microsoft-report-viewer-2012-update-a-gotcha-to-be-aware-of/)

<del>I installed the update [SQLServer2008R2SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747)</del>

I downloaded [ReportViewer.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747), which required to have installed [Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 <sup>(look halfway down the page for installer)</sup>](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)

In the GAC was now available WebForms v11.0.0.0 (`C:\Windows\assembly\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` `v11.0.0.0` as well as `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` `v11.0.0.0`)

Comment: also needed to restart the application pool before the newly installed dll's were picked up.

Comment: **Update:** Consider using NUGET - see section "Updating an existing project to use the ReportViewer control" in Microsoft article ["Integrating Reporting Services Using ReportViewer Controls - Get Started"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017#updating-an-existing-project-to-use-the-reportviewer-control). After updating it via NUGET check the "CopyLocal" setting (should be set to true).

Comment: Thanks. I needed to install Microsoft® System CLR Types first before I installed the ReportViewer.msi but after installing both my application now build properly. Thanks again.You can get the installer here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Answer (score 48):

I've installed Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime/) and problem has been solved without installing ReportViewer.msi or sql feature pack 12

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I was in need to getting v12 .dlls on a build server (TeamCity) that only had v11 available. There's a 2015 release package available on NuGet

Comment: this helped thanks  , there are many authors in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.ReportViewer) which you can choose from  but as suggested in answer i used  package created by Author `Fornax`    and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime/) is **link to install via nuget**

Comment: I think this answer save a day for me

Comment: This worked for me, though I didn't specify the 2012.runtime.  Instead I did  "Install-Package Microsoft.Report.Viewer" in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: For version 11.0.0 I used that Microsoft.ReportViewer package which you can see in the results of the picture and there was no problem

Comment: This worked for me, just stopped, installed the package, F5 and voilà.

Answer (score 23):

You need to reference both Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and set the CopyLocal property to true.  This will result in the dll's being copied to our bin directory (both are necessary).

Comment: I followed the steps above and have referenced `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` (v11) but cannot locate `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` (v11). Any ideas why I cannot see the `common` library?

Comment: I found Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\..., thanks to  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25797192/560114).

Comment: I installed ReportViewer as in a previous answer but that didn't work. This answer got me to a point where I was getting a new exception that told me to add ReportViewer to my web.config file. Once I fixed web.config I was sorted.

Answer (score 9):

I've solved the problem by copying both

- **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll** from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer`
- and **Microsoft.reportviewer.common.dll** from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in`

into bin folder (website).

Of course `web.config` must have:

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <assemblies>

        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </assemblies>

    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </buildProviders>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

And that's all.
For me is ok.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **validate="false"**, **system.webServer** `validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"` and `preCondition="integratedMode"` are required ?

Answer (score 2):

Updating ReportViewer should works. Use below instruction to install updated ReportViewer from Nuget Package Manager console.

> Install-Package
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms

Just add below assembly reference in your aspx file.

> 

Here, **15.0.0.0** is the version number of the ReportViewerControl.WebForms that was installed in my VS. Please check Reference of the Solution to confirm the version number. No need to add PublicTokens *(if multiple installation exists, it may creates trouble again).*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. My web app was pointed towards report viewer version 10.0 however if 11.0 is installed it adds a redirect in the 10.0 .dll to 11.0. This became an issue when 11.0 was uninstalled as this does not correct the redirect in the 10.0 .dll. The fix in my case was to simply uninstall and reinstall 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with an old webforms app. Turns out there was a line in the markup causing the issue. I removed it and the error disappeared.

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

Comment: So, that is simply not necessary anymore?

Comment: @tnk479 Well, nothing simple about ReportViewer :) but that did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when going from version 10.0.0.0, i.e. 
"Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

to version 11.0.0.0, i.e.

"Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

It took a while until I understood that not only the version was changed but also the public token key, as you can see above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error for a different package. My problem was that a dependent project was referencing a different version. I changed them to be the same version and all was good.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. Copy dll Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll into Bin folder in your project.
2. Remove your reference.
3. Add new reference from bin folder.

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll to your bin directory of your web applicaion.

You can find this dll file in the bin directory of your local web application.

Comment: hey thanks @Amit Mittal , I already have added reference to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, as wel as to Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll

Comment: Since you are getting error after uploading, this means that the report viewer dlls are not installed at the sserver. That is why you have to either install report viewer controls as server or manually upload dll files to the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

My trial version of DevExpress had expired. Try renewing it again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Run Report Viewer On server with Data from Server

**A)** Go to Project Property ----> Select Reference ------> Add Reference

**1)** Import (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll)-----> (Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer")

**2)** Import (Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll) -----> (Path "C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel")

**3)** Import (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll)-----> (Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer")

**B)** In Above three DLL set its "Local Copy" to True so that while Building Deployment Package it will getcopied to "Bin" folder.

**C)** Publish the Solution

**D)** After that Upload all the files along with "Bin" folder with the help of "File Zilla" software to "Web Server".

**E)** This will install DLL on server hence, client is not required to have "Report Viewer.dll".

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed the problem by installing Microsoft-Report-Viewer-2010-Redistributable ("ReportViewer.exe)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Microsoft-Report-Viewer-2010-Redistributable  in your server.
Download it and install