# ReportService2005 and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am having difficulty working in ReportService2005 into my MVC5 project.

When I run this code:

```
 MainReport.ServerReport.ReportPath = "BLAHBLAHFILEPATH";
 Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter rp = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("TEST","TEST",true);
 MainReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(rp); //error occurs here
 MainReport.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I come across this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.XmlSerializers, 
Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have reinstalled all of these but the error still occurs:

> MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME
>
> Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012
>
> Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005
>
> Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005 Service Pack 1

(Some of which were suggested here: [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493817/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms-version-11-0-0))

Any ideas? I also added the NuGet Package to my references.

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms is version 11, while Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common is version 10

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0/33670464#33670464)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was a red herring. The issue I really was having was answered here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2013/10/16/microsoft-reportviewer-setparameters-continuous-refresh-issue.aspx