# ASP.NET Register Assembly error

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis

I am WAY out of my league here, so I apologize if I'm asking a duplicate question, but I don't know where to start on this one.

I recently migrated an SQL database from SERVER1, where it was collocated with IIS hosting the web interface to access the database, to SERVER2. The web interface is now accessing the database properly, and through some application features I can access the data properly, with no error. However, when I try to run a report, I get this error:

How do I fix this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 5:      Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
Line 6:      TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
Line 7:  <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Line 8:      Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
Line 9:  


Source File: /source/Report5.aspx    Line: 7 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4028
```

**UPDATE**

I turned on logging and got this more detailed error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = AURORAFCS\raj
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Family/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Family\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Family\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
```

**UPDATE2**

Using fusion logger, I have this more detailed message, which shoes it a is a "File Cannot Be Found" error. However, I have installed the redistributables, so why can it not find the DLL?

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/21/2014 @ 4:00:35 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = AURORAFCS\raj
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Family/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Family\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc46260e
LOG: Cache Base = c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc46260e
LOG: AppName = 807e5b0d
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Family\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dc46260e/807e5b0d/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Family/bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16493817/656243).

Comment: Can you look in your project and select the references and report which version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll is being included?

Comment: (I don't do asp.net I'm just trying to manage a network that has not been managed in years, so I'll do my best to get you the right information. This app was built by someone who is no longer around and the app isn't used except to retrieve old records. I just needed to deal with the SQL server)

Comment: In the Report5.aspx source that I am trying to view through the web app, I only see a call to `DisplayName = Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0`

Comment: My big question is: why is the webserver not looking in C:\windows\assembly for the file?

Comment: That is why I was asking it sounds like your developer could have included a version of the dll in the project that you copy and deploy that is not the correct version. The files in your project's bin folder are first explored for matching file names then it shoots out from there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine what version of the ReportViewer Control you are targeting and install the proper package on the same server that your web app is deployed.

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 SP1 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3841)

[Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=577)

[Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916)

I am sure the logic is as follows:

- ReportViewer 2010 can be used against SQL Server 2008(SP2) and 2012
- ReportViewer 2008 can be used against SQL Server 2008 and 2005
- ReportViewer 2005 can be used against SQL Server 2005

Comment: I just saw your comment above.

Comment: RV 2010 ---> SSRS 2008(SP2) 2012 | RV 2008 --> SSRS 2005/2008 | RV 2005 --> SSRS 2005. I am pretty sure that is it.

Comment: How do I determine that?

Comment: The main factor is the version of sql server that is installed on your server. VS 2012 and 2008 ship with different versions of the control you are using at design time. What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: 2005, which is what the previous database was. However, it came from a 2005sp3 where this one is 2005sp1

Comment: Does it matter that it's coming from server 2003 x86 to server 2008r2 x64 ?

Comment: You should use the 2005 redistributable. That targets the ReportExecution2005 interface which is compatible with sql server 2005.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I'm going to hug both of you if this works.

Comment: Well, I've downloaded 2005 ReDistributable and sp1 for it, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I found Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 8.0.0.0 with a matching Public Key Token in the GAC (C:\Windows\Assembly) but I'm still having an error... do I need to reset any connections or cached something or another?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem in this blog:

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/access-report-viewer-dll-files-for-your-application/

I just extracted the needed DLL and put it into one of the directories that the webapp was looking for. Still not sure why it happened, though.

Comment: Sounds like you are throwing that file into the Bin of a webfolder. Hope it works and whatever you place there will overrides the GAC.